# Timing issue with cancellationTOken and sync sql calls

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

(UPDATE: Due to Panagiotis Kanavos's request, I will try to be more explicit in what I try to achieve, hence I have changed the original post).

I have the need for being able to cancel a long-running query with a CancellationToken.

Say I have a data access method looking like this:

```
void DoSomethingLongRunningOnSql(CancellationToken token){
   ...
}
```

... and I have to be able to ensure, that no matter what the timing is, if the token's source has been cancelled, this method should not keep running.

The caller may do either this:

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;
```

In thread 1 this is called:

```
DoSomethingLongRunningOnSql(token); // Thread 1
```

In Thread 2, At the same time, the source may be cancelled:

```
source.Cancel(); // Thread 2
```

In this case I want the long-running query to just stop no matter if the source was cancelled before the query was started or after.

I cannot use the Async methods of the Sql-classes here, as this must work in an existing sync context. And switching between sync and async is prone to dead lock issues.

Based on Panagiotis' suggestions, the following example is the best I could come up with so far:

```
void DoSomethingLongRunningOnSql(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Avoid getting a connection from the pool if already cancelled.
    // This will ensure fast cancellation in the case that
    // connection pool is full and .Open() will hang.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        // It may in rare cases take some time to get a connection
        // from the connection pool, e.g. i max pool size has been reached
        conn.Open();

        // Throw if cancelled as close to the actual execution to lower
        // the risk of having the cancelation token canceled just before
        // executing the query, resulting in the query not being cancelled.
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand("Some long running query", conn);

        // Support for cancellation
        token.Register(() => cmd.Cancel());

        // PROBLEM: If the other thread happened to call cancel at this,
        // specific time, the query will not be cancelled and this call 
        // will hang until the query is done.

        // Execute the sql command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if this can be done in a 100% safe way or if I should just rely on the fact that it is likely to happen very rarely that cancel was called at the problematic timing?

Comment: This is a bug in the code. It called `Cancel()` on a command that wasn't even running. Both snippets are wrong if you want to cancel a command after a timeout. The first one nukes the thread.

Comment: The correct way to cancel the query after a timeout, set the [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8) property. That's very different from throwing an exception or calling `Cancel()`.

Comment: Finally the two snippets don't even try to do the same thing. The first one tries to cancel after 2 minutes, the second one immediately. To compare them, the second snippet should use [CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: "Finally the two snippets don't even try to do the same thing". This is by intention to state my point: The real life scenario is, that the cancellation is parsed into a method that will handle the sql execution. I cannot be sure whether cancel has already been called when the token is parsed into my production-method or not. So both scenarios must behave the same way.

The only way I can make the example 2 work as intended is my calling token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() myself just before executing the command.

But this solution would not be 100% safe.

Comment: If you want to create an overall operation timeout, you should use [ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReaderAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). This method [checks for cancellation before it even starts executing](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,2477) and doesn't block either. Otherwise you'll have to call `IsCancellationRequested` before starting

Comment: "Otherwise you'll have to call IsCancellationRequested before starting" - but can we agree on that this solution would not be 100% safe in case the token is cancelled by another thread just after my check but before executing the command?

Comment: On the contrary, it's perfectly safe. It's built for exactly this. There's no `just after` - what happens if cancellation is requested after `ExecuteReader` starts but before that method had a chance to reach its second statement? You still haven't explained what the *actual* problem is, you described what you think the solution looks like. What's the actual problem?

Comment: Cancellation of the token will happen from another thread at an arbitrary time.
If I call ThrowIfCancellationRequested() in my code. Then the other thread may call "Cancel()" in the background BEFORE the next line of code in my method is executed. Makes sense?

Comment: From the start - that's why I'm saying that `Throw` or extra threads aren't needed.  And what you ask is already implemented in `ExecuteReaderAsync`. If you actually check the link to the source code, you'd see it uses code like your own

Comment: I am working in sync-mode here. Switching between async and sync is prone to deadlock issues.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Based on all you suggestions I have rewritten the original post to be more precise. I have added the manual cancel-calls. I hope it is more clear now, what I want to achieve? :)

Comment: I mean I guess you could use a lock, but it seems overkill... really you want to just switch to async code

Comment: Milney. yes, idealy, maybe. But reality is, that this is a small part of a big existing solution running in sync mode with multiple threads.